# Android app is slow after sdk upgrade

Tags: java, android, sdk

I upgraded my SDK on my android studio, since then I get the following error for my previously normal working app on my emulator.

The following is log:

```
05-24 08:27:26.297 21141-21141/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-24 08:27:26.298 21141-21141/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-24 08:27:29.194 21141-21141/x.x.x.x W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/x.x.x.x-2/lib/x86
05-24 08:27:42.848 21141-21141/x.x.x.x I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-24 08:27:46.497 21141-21241/x.x.x. I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-24 08:27:46.497 21141-21241/x.x.x.x D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-24 08:27:46.498 21141-21241/x.x.x.x W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
05-24 08:27:46.498 21141-21241/x.x.x.x D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
05-24 08:28:03.756 21141-21141/x.x.x.x I/Choreographer: Skipped 1254 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

The following is stub of my activity

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.IOException;
import model.DatabaseHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button genbutton;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

For even this empty activity, it is skipping more than 1000 frames. The XML for the activity is very simple with few buttons and a picture(100k). How can I solve the issue? Most solutions on internet recommended to use async task and threading. But here I have empty activity.

Comment: I had same logs but on real devices app has an usual performance as well as other apps. I didn't notice any slow behavior.

Comment: that may be an Emulator issue, try on real device first before doing panic.

Comment: I clearly remember this 'doing too much work on main thread' was appearing before upgrade, but my app worked without any lag on emulator and users' devices.I have never tested on real device that version. Now after upgrade, when I try to test on real device, my app can no longer find the path of my sqlite DB.

Comment: I just attached dummy empty xml to the activity, and the error disappeared. So new version of android studio does not like something in my old xml which was completely normal on prev version.Will update soon.

Comment: The app is working fine on real device.Thanks Shah and Vlad.